# Split lines delimited by string into new files as columns Bash script

Tags: bash, sed, split, grep, gnu

I have a data file like following:

```
>> cat file1.txt
@target G0.S0
1 6 
1 4 
4 2 
@target G0.S0
2 4 
8 9 
5 7 
@target G0.S0
3 5 
0 9 
3 7
```

I want to make split columns delimited by `@target G0.S0` in a new file where columns set one next the previous ones like following:

```
>> cat file2.txt
1 6 2 4 3 5
1 4 8 9 0 9
4 2 5 7 3 7
```

I searched in internet but I don't get what I want.

Comment: If you split your problem into two sub-problems, you should find solutions which you then can combine yourself: 1. Split one file at a string into many files (e.g. with `awk`) 2. Combine multiple files side by side (e.g. with `paste`). Good luck!

Comment: will all `@target` lines end with `G0.50` or do we need to worry about different targets? if there will be different targets please update the question with a sample, making sure to update the expected output, too;  are all 'matching' target groups guaranteed to have the same number of lines (`3` in this case)?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 2):

A quick one-liner with `pr`, `grep` and `tail` with the shell.

```
pr "-$(grep -Fc '@target G0.S0' file1.txt)ts"' ' file1.txt | tail -n +2
```

---

Redirect the output to a new file.

```
pr ... > file2.txt
```

---

Let us break it down a bit.

- `pr` is a printing utility.
- `grep -Fc '@target G0.S0' file1.txt` expand to a number see: `grep --help | grep -E -- ' -(F|c)'`
- `$( )` is called [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).
- `t` and `s` are options for `pr` see: `pr --help | grep -E -- '^ *-(s|t)'`
- `tail` prints starting from the second line, see: `tail --help | grep -- -n`
- In the end the command expanded to: `pr -Nts' '`, where `N` an int/number.

---

As mentioned by `@Socowi`, there are a lot of limitations as it is written. The code works with the assumption that all lines in between `@target G0.S0` are all equal/same amount of lines, in this case 3 lines in between `@target G0.S0`. (Which is where I have based the answer), also if there are too many (long data/input) size, an additional option should be added, the `-w`. Like what I have mentioned, If the file/data/size/input is large/huge, then the `awk` solution is preferred.

---

- With a large data size/file I would go with `awk` instead.

Comment: You might want to point out, that this command assumes that all sections (those between `@target ...`) have the same number of lines.

Comment: In case there are a lot of section, you might get the error `pr: page width too narrow` (you can try this with `seq 99 | pr -99ts' '`). In that case, you have set a custom page width (`-w`)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, assuming stride is 4 and naming your script `concat` and giving it exec permission:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -vN=4 -f

(NR-1)%N==0 {next}
{i=int(NR-2)%N;a[i]=(a[i] ? a[i] " " : "")  $0}
END {for (i=0; i<N; i++){print a[i]}}
```

then

```
./concat file1.txt > file2.txt
```

gives

```
1 6 2 4 3 5
1 4 8 9 0 9
4 2 5 7 3 7
```

in `file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

**single `awk` procedure solution**

The following suggestion accumulates lines in an array indexed by reference to the line number (a decrement and remainder division used to cycle indexes 1-3, storing lines 2-4, 6-8, 10-12 etc, concatenating each time). The condition before the main block excludes rows 1,5,9 etc. The END block iterates the array to print the output which is redirected to the desired new file name.

```
awk ' (NR-1)%4!=0{lines[(NR-1)%4]=lines[(NR-1)%4]$0}
END{ for(line=1; line<4; line++) {print lines[line]}
} ' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (csplit, paste and sed):

```
csplit -qz --suppress file '/@target/' '{*}' && paste -d' ' xx* |
sed 's/  / /g' >outFile && rm xx*
```

Split the input file into consecutively numbered files containing the one row for each column to be appended.

Paste the intermediate files, separated by a space.

Take the output from the above ,remove the additional spaces, output to a final file and clean up.

---

A GNU sed only solution:

```
sed -nE '/\n/!{:a;N;$!ba}
         s/^@/\n@/;s/\S$/& /mg;tb
         :b;s/^([^\n]*)((\n[^@]*)*)\n@[^\n]*\n([^\n]+)/\1\4\2\n/;tb
         s/ \n/\n/;P;s/\n+$//;s/\n\n/\n@\n/g;D' file
```

If the file has not been slurped into the pattern space (memory), slurp the file.

Introduce a newline at the start of the pattern space and provide a space at the end of each line.

Iterate through the file, appending the values on the first line following a header line to the first line of the pattern space. Replacing each header as it is processed by two newlines.

Remove the introduced spaces at the end of the line and print the first line of the pattern space.

If all the lines have been processed the end of the pattern space will only consist of newlines, in which case remove them.

Otherwise, re-introduce a pseudo header by inserting an `@` between each occurrence of two newlines.

Delete the printed line and begin the sed process again if there are still lines to process.